# Sorting table with query

Tags: php, database

I want to sort this table, order by RESULT. but, the result of RESULT doesn't stored in database. What can i do? Thanks for your help.

data "Title & 1st number" is stored on table "table1".

data "2nd number" is stored on table "table2", but i just want to take one number.

data "result" does'nt stored on any table.

> Title | 1st number | 2nd number | substraction | result
>
> A | 80 | 65 | 80 - 65 | 15
>
> B | 78 | 43 | 78 - 65 | 35
>
> C | 100 | 95 | 100 - 65 | 5

I want to sort it by result. What should I use (query)? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT tbl1.title,tbl1.num1,tbl2.num2, CONCAT(tbl1.num1 , "-", tbl2.num2),(tbl1.num1 - tbl2.num2) as result 
FROM tbl1,tbl2 
ORDER BY result
```

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, i forget this:

I want to just get 1 number on "2nd number". For example:
80 - 65, 78 - 65, 100 - 65, ..., n - 65. What should i use?

Comment: @bob Is your problem solved or not? If solved then accept the answer..:)

Answer (score 1):

below is your correct solution to sorting in result column

```
SELECT (tbl1.num1 - tbl2.num2) as result,tbl1.id from  
                table1 as tbl1,table1  as tbl2 
                    where tbl1.id=tbl2.id  ORDER BY result Desc
```

let me know if i can help you more..

Comment: @bob is my answer is helpful to you ? is your problem is solved ? i would appreciate if you accept my answer.